# Solution of $y'=xy^{1/3}, y(0)=0$ equal to $0$ in $[-c,c]$ and positive for $|x|>c$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, continuity

I'm looking for a continuous function $y(x)$ which satisfies the above and trying to make it depend on $c$ so that a solution exists for any $c>0$. I read it is possible, but I can't do it... Can you help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes such solution DOES exist, and this is due to the fact that the IVP
$$
y'=xy^{1/3}, \quad y(0)=0, \tag{$\star$}
$$
does not enjoy uniqueness.

So we work as follows. In $[-c,c]$, our solution is identically zero. Then at $x=c$ satisfies the IVP
$$
y'=xy^{1/3}, \quad y(c)=0.
$$ 
If we assume that $y(x)\ne 0$, in some neighborhood $(c,c+\varepsilon)$, then we obtain (suitably integrating) that
$$
\frac{y'(x)}{y^{1/3}(x)}=x \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \frac{3}{2}y^{2/3}(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}+c_1
$$
for some constant $c_1$. But $y$ is continuous in $[c,c+\varepsilon)$ and $y(c)=0$, and hence $c_1=-c^2/2$. Thus, for $x\ge c$
$$
y(x)=\left(\frac{x^2-c^2}{3}\right)^{1/3}.
$$
Working similarly for $x\ge -c$ we obtain that if $y(x)\ne 0$, 
in some neighborhood $(-c-\varepsilon,-c)$, then again
$$
y(x)=-\left(\frac{c^2-x^2}{3}\right)^{1/3},
$$ 
for $x\le-c$. Altogether, a solution of the original IVP is
$$
y(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll} 0 & \text{if} & \lvert x\rvert\le c,\\
\left(\frac{x^2-c^2}{3}\right)^{1/3} & \text{if} & \lvert x\rvert>c.
\end{array}\right.
$$

**Important Note.** This IVP $(\star)$ possesses infinitely many solutions. For different
values of positive $c$ we have different solutions. In fact, there exists even more solutions, with can vanish in any interval $I$, with $0\in I$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I see now...

Answer (score 0):

The general solution for $$\frac{dy}{dx} = xy^{\frac{1}{3}}$$
can be found by solving

$$\int y^{-1/3}dy = \int xdx.$$

This simplifies to $$\frac{3}{2}y^{2/3} = \frac{x^2}{2} + C\\
y^{2/3} = \frac13 x^2 + D\\
y = \left(\frac13 x^2 + D\right)^{3/2}$$

meaning that if $y(0)=0$, then the solution is independent of $c$ and equal to 
$$\left(\frac13 x^2\right)^{3/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{27}} x^3$$